# Is it possible to send push notifications as per user preference(Time) from parse?

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Their is an option of scheduling in parse which schedules the pushes from the admin side but what i need  to achieve the same from the users side.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Parse feature background jobs. It only allows one background job to run at a time, but it should satisfy your requirements as long as they are not too lavish.

You can schedule a background job through the Rest Api  such as a background job to send out your push notifications. You could schedule them to be sent every so often or at a specific time each day and call it using a Cloud code.

Its very simple to use, so hopefully that works!